# First physical core to boot

Tags: linux-kernel, x86, arm, kernel, arm64

As I was reading through the kernel source code I noticed that a mapping between the physical core id and the virtual core number is being created. This could be because there is some degree of uncertainty in the order in which the cores are brought up.

In a multi-core system, which physical core is the first to boot? Is it ***always*** physical core #0? Does this hold for x86, x64, ARM and ARM64?

Comment: too broad.  ARM cores have separate resets that are controlled by the chip vendor (arm doesnt make chips, others do and use arm cores in their chips), so the vendor can do whatever release them all at once or one at a time in whatever order.   I also woudnt make generalizations with x86 since there are so many of them that have evolved over time.

Comment: read the documentation for each chip of interest.

Answer (score 3):

According to the Intel SDM, in recent Intel processors the selection of the bootstrap processor (BSP) is handled either "through a special system bus cycle" or "by platform-specific arrangement of the combination of hardware, BIOS, and/or configuration input options."

In my experience (with Intel processors only), the BSP always has APIC ID 0 (although this is not guaranteed). However, I don't know whether that means that it is always the same physical core within the processor, or even if there is any way to tell.

For more information, see section 8.4 of the Intel SDM, volume 3A.

Comment: 8.4.3 seems to describe the procedure pretty definitively, what's vague about it?

Comment: @Michael, thanks, I had only looked at the intro to 8.4.